# Write automated test case with dynamic controls

Tags: .net, testing, automation

I am currently analyzing an internal tool which can help us write automated test case for static and non static controls. From my teams observation I hear the automation of dynamic controls seems very time consuming. Its asp.net web page. Currently i am using custom tool using .net and win32 calls to interop with IE for most tasks.

Have any one of you automated test cases with dynamic controls?